# Под какую версию Android стоит разрабатывать приложения?

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Я пытаюсь начать разрабатывать приложения под андроид. Возник вопрос - под какую версию андроид нужно разрабатывать приложения? Например, у меня на планшете android 4.0.3, будет ли там работать приложение под android 4.2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если Вы будете разрабатывать приложение под 4.2, то будет ли оно работать на предыдущих версиях, зависит в основном только от того, какие функции используются. Если на сайте d.android.com найти нужные классы/методы, то справа вверху найдете надпись "Added in API Level 4" или подобное. Каждая версия андроида поддерживает свой [api level](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels).

Поэтому, если Вы будете писать под 4.2 андроид, но использовать только функции 11 апи левела, то работать будет и на андроиде 3.0. Обратная совместимость достаточно хорошо работает и если не использовать каких-то изощренных методов, то программа, написанная для младших версий, будет работать на страрших (правда она может не соответствовать стилю и плохо масштабироваться, но работать будет)

> Возник вопрос - под какую версию андроид нужно разрабатывать приложения?

Если Вы делаете для себя - тогда ориентируйтесь на Ваше устройство. Если же решили сделать для широкой публики, то на данный момент актуально делать под 8 api level и старше (учитывая [эту](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) таблицу).

На практике часто применяют методику, когда код сам проверяет текущий апи левел и по надобности использует апи более высокого уровня.

> Плюс, ко всему прочему, в новой версии, по-мимо добавления каких-либо деталей могут просто взять и перепилить всю архитектуру к примеру (там иерархию наследования к примеру и т.п.)
>  [@SoloMio](/users/10292/solomio)

Такое могут сделать к примеру на BlackBerry, где просто сказали, что старые методы больше не работают, вот вам новое апи, новая среда разработки. В случае с андроидом, это стараются более плавно делать. Более того, в стандартной поставке есть так называемые support пакеты - это когда функциональность, которая доступна только на новых версиях делают доступной (backport) на более ранних. К примеру - фрагменты.

Answer (score 2):

Когда приложение пишешь, ведь там указывается минимальная версия. Вот если ты выбираешь android 4.0.3, то все выше будут поддерживаться. А наоборот - нет

Comment: Ну это понятно, но интересно, насколько хорошо поддерживаются приложения 4.2 на андроиде 4.0.3, например. Ну есть ли большая разница или в основном багфиксы и небольшие редкоиспользуемые изменения?

Answer (score 1):

Не спец по андроиду, но рискну ответить:

1. Нужно - под ту версию, число пользователей которой вы хотите обеспечить полнофункциональной версией вашей программы. Т.е. если больше всего пользователей именно платформы 4.0.2, и переход в ближайший меся-два на новую платформу не намечается, то есть смысл заточить вашу апликуху под старую верчсию андроида.
2. Приложение, написанное на 4.2, навряд ли будет работать на 4.0.3, хотя это утверждение, конечно же, спорное. Все зависит от функционала новой ОС, который вы задействуете. Вполне может быть, что апликуха, написанная вами с использованием SDK 4.2, будет вполне бинарно совместимо с рантаймом более старой версии - опять-таки, в новой версии ОС те же API могут выдавать несколько иной результат, нежели тот, что вы привыкли видеть, запуская ваше приложение на 4.2.

В-общем надо все взвесить, оценить (спрогнозировать) скорость перехода, и от этого уже отталкиватся и принимать решение.  Согласитесь, что сейчас бессмысленно при разработке приложения для Windows оглядываться на Windows 95 и Windows ME, ибо если кто и пользуется этими бесконечно устаревшими версия этой операционки, то их процент настолько мал, что навряд ли уместно совершать какие-либо лишние трудозатраты по подгонке версий своей программы под эти устаревшие версии ОС.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Ну я полагаю, что поддерживать пользователей версии андроид 4.0 и выше вполне разумно.

Comment: Плюс, ко всему прочему, в новой версии, по-мимо добавления каких-либо деталей могут просто взять и перепилить всю архитектуру к примеру (там иерархию наследования к примеру и т.п.)

Comment: Вот именно об этом я и думал, когда спрашивал.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что ко всему выше сказанному можно добавить [ссылку](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) на ежемесячную статистику используемых версий Android проводимой Google, где можно увидеть тенденции.

Comment: в моем ответе ссылка на эту таблицу также приведена:)

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая штука [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) библиотека поддержки фич старших АПИ в младших. В частности с ее помощью можно применять `Fragment`ы в GingerBread и т.д.

Читайте документацию.

В экосистеме Android'а грубо говоря есть 3 больших острова: GingerBread - примерно половина, ICS - четверть и JellyBean - 15% - все остальное это мелочь.

Так что лучше всего писать под GingerBread (API Level 10) + библиотека суппорта - гарантированно > 90% девайсов будут ваши.